# How to set macro for system.profile.name in cloud datafusion pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to send system.profile.name runtime args in below airflow dag:

```
start_pipeline = CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator(
    task_id="start_pipeline",
    location="us-central1",
    pipeline_name="cdf_pipeline",
    instance_name="cdf_instance",
    runtime_args={"system.profile.name":'SYSTEM{COMPUTE_PROFILE}'},
    dag=dag
)
```

But my cdf_pipeline is deployed and i am not able to macro it. could you please suggest how to pass compute profile name through runtime_args through CloudDataFusionStartPipelineOperator and also how to set macro for compute profile?

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to use CDAP macros, you'll need to prepend your macro with $. For details, see https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/1188036697/Macros+and+macro+functions.